# OpenCv Linker Error: Symbol not found: ___itt_api_version_ptr__3_0

Tags: python, c++, opencv3.0

I am trying to build OpenCV 3.4.3 off of the source and I am creating a library for using with my Python code. I see the following error:

```
import vision_library
ImportError: dlopen(/home/ssk/pyVision/python_scripts/vision_library.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___itt_api_version_ptr__3_0
  Referenced from: /home/ssk/pyVision/python_scripts/vision_library.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Here is the CMAKE build command:

```
# Set Build Variables
PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE='/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7'
PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR='/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7'
PYTHON2_LIBRARY='/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.dylib' # TODO - Fix for linux
PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS='/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy/core/include' # Todo - Fix for linux


cd $OPENCV_DIR

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$OPENCV_INSTALL_PATH \
                                  -D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
                                  -D WITH_IPP=OFF \
                                  -D WITH_CLP:BOOL=ON \
                                  -D BUILD_opencv_python2:BOOL=ON \
                                  -D PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=$PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE \
                                  -D PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR=$PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR \
                                  -D PYTHON2_LIBRARY=$PYTHON2_LIBRARY \
                                  -D PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS=$PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS \
                                  -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES:BOOL=ON \
                                  -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
                                  ..
make -j8
make install
```

How to disable ITT? I don't need that for my use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ITT can be disabled by in the above cmake:

```
-D WITH_ITT=OFF \
```